# How to set the fit property for video player in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm using [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin to show video in Flutter.
As there is a `fit` property with Images in Flutter which we can set to `BoxFit.cover`
I want to do the same with video player as well.

```
Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: VideoPlayer(
                  _controller,
                )),
          ),
       ]
     )
```

[image: Extra space of the container should not be there]
I want the video to fit the container.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be possible.

On `Web` the package is actually using html `video` element to render your video and the only way to resize the `video` tag would be to use the below css property.

```
object-fit: fill
```

It doesn't work with just the `height` and `width` control since on web, the html `video` element just takes up the extra space but doesn't automatically resize the video content.

Use this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_width_height) and try increasing the `height` of the `video`. You will observe that despite it expanding to take the new height, the actual content only appears in a smaller box.

So, considering how `object-fit` css property is the only way, I tried to comb through the [video_player_web](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web) package to look for any specific control it provides over css.

But unfortunately, there is no such functionality provided as of yet. As mentioned in their `pub` page,

> Note: This plugin is still under development, and some APIs might not be available yet. Feedback welcome and Pull Requests are most welcome!

Very disappointed :(

Comment: @Apoorvpandey could you update your question with screenshots of what is expected and what you actually getting ?

Comment: I have added the ss for the code I originally had.
There is another container with the Icon in stack but that won't matter I guess.

Comment: Im checking it, will get back to you once I find out what the issue is.

Comment: The sizing issue seems to be occurring on web only.

Comment: Have upvoted your question as well, would love to know a workaround.

Comment: video_player_web is unlisted! apart from this in general I have faced many other issues relating to videos in Flutter as well.

Comment: I see. have you tried any other packages ?